# Using Home & Student edition Office on Vista for Business

Tags: windows-vista

I have a machine running Windows Vista for Business which I legitimately 'inherited' from an employer when they made me redundant.

I have no real use for this machine, so would like to give it to my father who is currently languishing on a very slow Windows XP machine, where he mainly does standard office style tasks using Microsoft Office Home & Student edition (he's a semi-retired university lecturer).

Will MS Office Home & Student edition work correctly with Vista for Business or will it complain because of the conflicting target audiences?

Answer (score 0):

No. Office does not care which edition of Windows it is installed on, only the version. For example, Office 2010 has its system requirements spelled out [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/products/microsoft-office-2010-system-requirements-HA101810407.aspx) does not say anything about the edition of Windows.